# listView com imagem texto e subtítulo

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragment, android-adapter

Estou montando um app de vendas, onde um usuário vai publicar seu produto com: imagem, preço, descrição e valor.

Eu consigo listar a foto tudo certo mas não consigo colocar um titulo e as demais descrições

Aqui está a minha lista e meu adapter.

```java
public class OfertasAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ParseObject> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ParseObject> publicacoes;

    public OfertasAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<ParseObject> objects) {
        super(c, 0, objects);
        this.context = c;
        this.publicacoes = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {

            //Inicializa objeto para montagem do layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            //Monta a view a partir do xml
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_publicacoes, parent, false);
        }
            //Verifica se existe postagens
        if (publicacoes.size() > 0) {

            //Recupera componentes da tela
            ImageView imagemPostagem = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_lista_publicacoes);

            ParseObject parseObject = publicacoes.get(position);

            //parseObject.getParseFile( "imagem" );
            Picasso.with(context)
            .load( parseObject.getParseFile( "imagem" ).getUrl() )
            .fit()
            .into( imagemPostagem );


         }


        return view;
    }

}
```

esse aqui é o processo de salvar a imagem no banco de dados

```java
public class PublicarOfertasActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView botaoPublicar;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private Button botaoPublicar2;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_publicar_ofertas);
        botaoPublicar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePublicar);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager_main);
        /*configurar adapter novo
        TabsAdapter  tabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabsAdapter);*/




        botaoPublicar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                publicarOfertas();
            }
        });
    }

    private void publicarOfertas() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        //testar o processo de retorno dos dados
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {


            //Recuperar local do recurso
            Uri localImagemSelecionada = data.getData();



            //Recupera a imagem do local que foi selecionada
            try {
                Bitmap imagem = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), localImagemSelecionada);

                /*
                Comprimir imagem no formato PNG
                 */
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                imagem.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 75, stream);

                /*Comprimir imagem no formato JPG!!!
                */
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                imagem.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, stream2);

                /*Cria 2 Arrays de Bytes da imagem tanto PNG quanto JPEG
                */
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                byte[] byteArray2 = stream2.toByteArray();

                /*Cria arquivos com formato proprio do Parse para PNG e JPEG
                 */
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddmmaaaahhmmss");
                String nomeImagem = dateFormat.format(new Date());
                ParseFile arquivoParse = new ParseFile(nomeImagem + "imagem.png", byteArray);
                ParseFile arquivoParse2 = new ParseFile(nomeImagem + "imagem.jpeg", byteArray2);

                /*Monta um objeto para salvar no Parse
                 */
                ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject("Imagem");
                parseObject.put("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());

                /*Atribui 2 entradas de dados no objeto "imagem", para PNG e JPEG
                 */
                parseObject.put("imagem", arquivoParse);
                parseObject.put("imagem", arquivoParse2);




                //Salvar os dados
                parseObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {

                        if (e == null) {//Sucesso
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sua imagem foi postada!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           /* TabsAdapter adapterNovo = (TabsAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter();
                            OfertasDoDia ofertasDoDiaNovo =(OfertasDoDia) adapterNovo.getFragment(1);
                            ofertasDoDiaNovo.atualizaPublicacoes();*/

                        } else {//Erro
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Erro ao postar sua imagem, tente novamente!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }


                    }


                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    }
```

e aqui eu listo as imagens no fragment

```java
public class OfertasDoDia extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<ParseObject> publicacoes;
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayAdapter<ParseObject> adapter;
    private ParseQuery<ParseObject> recuperaImagem;



    public OfertasDoDia() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ofertas_do_dia, container, false);

        //montar listview e adapter

        publicacoes = new ArrayList<>();
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_publicacoes);
        adapter= new OfertasAdapter(getActivity(),publicacoes);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //recupera postagens
        getPublicacoes();

        return view;
    }
    private void getPublicacoes(){
            recuperaImagem = ParseQuery.getQuery("Imagem");


       // query.whereEqualTo( "username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername() );
        recuperaImagem.orderByDescending("createdAt");
        recuperaImagem.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

                if ( e == null ){//Sucesso

                    if ( objects.size() > 0 ){
                        publicacoes.clear();
                        for ( ParseObject parseObject : objects ){
                            publicacoes.add( parseObject );
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                }else{//Erro
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Primeiro você tem que capturar a nome do produto. Pelo que vejo você pega a imagem ali no ParseQuery,getQuery("Image"). Desta mesma forma, você consegue pegar o nome do produto? Esse seria o primeiro passo.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta,pensei nisso tbm mas a duvida seria como montar  as linhas de codigo

Comment: Eu sei como fazer, o que não sei é de onde você puxa as outras informações além dá imagem. Ninguém respondeu ainda porque na sua questão falta mais informações.

Comment: nao tem outras informaçoes man, eu só puxo a imagem

Comment: Você puxa a imagem de onde man?

Comment: puxo do banco de dados do parse

Comment: um cara me disse que no banco de dados eu poderia criar mais uma coluna alem da imagem que seria a desccricao, dai eu puxaria a descriçao igual puxo a imagem, mas eu tentei e nao deu certo, devo estar escrevendo o codigo errado....vc poderia me dar uma luz?

Comment: Sim, se não existe a descrição no banco, você tem que criar, e puxar desta mesma forma como está fazendo com a imagem. Esse banco é externo ou interno? Verifique onde foi criado a tabela e acrescente o a coluna 'descricao'... É difícil te ajudar não tendo as informações suficientes man, porque listar imagem e texto é muito simples, porém precisamos retornar primeiro a descrição pra depois listar ela.

Comment: O banco é externo, chamado parse, se puder me dizer do q vc precisa pra poder me ajudar ficarei grato

Answer (score 0):

Para carregar imagem e texto para um ListView personalizado,
não há nada melhor que o LazyAdapter. Talvez você precise refazer parte do código, mas vale à pena.

[Essa questão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294243/listview-image-and-text-with-custom-adapter) no Stack em inglês está bem completa com exemplo.
Além disso tem um todo completo para você [aqui no GitHub](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList/blob/master/src/com/fedorvlasov/lazylist/MainActivity.java)

Ah, se estiver armazenando as imagens no banco, não faça isso, nunca!
Ao invés, salve o link para a pasta onde a imagem se localiza e recupere com sua linguagem preferida [ PHP :) ], e retorne tudo (imagens e textos) no formato **JSON** do banco de dados através de uma página no servidor.

(Leia sobre WebService PHP)